# How to move grub from one disk to another?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive, ssd

For what it's worth, I have reviewed all the other questions similar to this and the suggested steps did not work.  Here is my situation:

I have a 10+ year old system (don't say upgrade it, because I am unable to do so).  This system had 2 500GB HDDs, one of which is well over 10 years old (from my previous system) and the other is original with the system (10+ years old).  I recently purchased 2 480GB SSDs.  I used Partition Wizard to easily move the Windows drive to it's SSD.  Moving the Ubuntu drive has been a bit of a nightmare.  This drive is also where grub is installed.  I performed the following steps:

1. Using Partition Wizard, cloned the Windows HDD to its new SDD home (/dev/sdb --> /dev/sdd)
2. Booted into Ubuntu and ran `update-grub2` to create a menu entry for the new Windows drive
3. Partitioned the SSD to contain the Ubuntu disk using `gpartd`
4. Using `rsync` copied the contents if `/` to `/dev/sdc1` mounted as `/mnt`
5. ran `grub-install /dev/sdc` after unmounting it, which ran successfully.
6. ran `update-grub2` to create a menu entry for the new Ubuntu disk.
7. rebooted into grub and selected the Ubuntu on /dev/sdc.  It actually booted into the original Ubuntu on /dev/sda.
8. used `gpartd` to set the boot flag for `/dev/sdc1`.
9. booted back into grub and successfully booted into Ubuntu on /dev/sdc1
10. ran `update-grub2` on Ubuntu on `/dev/sdc1` to get the menu to contain all the bootable O/S's listed.
11. rebooted again to make sure everything worked and then shut everything down.
12. unplugged the old drives
13. restarted the system into the BIOS to configure the SDD containing `/dev/sdc` partition as the first device in the boot order, save and containued
14. The system never found a boot device.
15. rebooted into BIOS and swapped SSDs in the boot order, saved and continued.
16. same result.
17. plugged the old hard drive back in and rebooted into grub and selected the Ubuntu on `/dev/sdc` (which is from where I am writting this)

My disk environment is as such:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
loop0    7:0    0    16M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-budgie-welcome/176
loop1    7:1    0  15.9M  1 loop /snap/ubuntu-budgie-welcome/167
loop2    7:2    0 147.5M  1 loop /snap/postman/99
loop3    7:3    0  54.7M  1 loop /snap/core18/1668
loop4    7:4    0  91.3M  1 loop /snap/core/8592
loop5    7:5    0 193.3M  1 loop /snap/mailspring/407
loop6    7:6    0  44.9M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
loop7    7:7    0  91.4M  1 loop /snap/core/8689
loop8    7:8    0   193M  1 loop /snap/mailspring/440
loop9    7:9    0 147.8M  1 loop /snap/postman/100
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 465.8G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1  29.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  29.8G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 447.1G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 447.1G  0 part /
sdd      8:48   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sdd1   8:49   0 240.8M  0 part 
└─sdd2   8:50   0 446.9G  0 part /mnt/01D5FAFF489A8BB0
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

- `/dev/sda` is Ubuntu 19.10 on the HDD (this is where grub was originally installed)
- `/dev/sdb` is Windows 10 on the HDD
- `/dev/sdc` is Ubuntu 19.10 on the SSD (this is device supplied on `grub-install`)
- `/dev/sdd` is Windows 10 on the SSD

I can successfully unplug the Windows HDD and all works as expected.  If I unplug the Ubuntu HDD, the system will not boot into Grub.  In the mean time, I have re-plugged in the Ubuntu HDD until I can get past this issue.  So, here are my questions:

1. Is there something wrong with what I have done?
2. What am I missing?
3. What am I doing or have I done wrong?

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oldfred's comment and linked worked perfectly.  It did reset some of the customizations I had, but I was able to fully disconnect the old hard drive.  For reference, if you are having issues after copying or moving a disk, look at [this post](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for more information that should help.